# add a single spaces in list containing characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I am new to the programming. I have a list. List contains multiple spaces. All the multiple spaces should be replaced with single space.

```
lis = ['h','e','l','l','','','','','o','','','','w']

output = ['h','e','l','l','','o','','w']
```

Could anyone tell how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `enumerate` 
and select only those `''` which 
follow non-empty characters themselves

```
[c for i, c in enumerate(lis) if c or (not c and lis[i - 1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simple list comprehension will suffice:

```
lis = ['h','e','l','l','','','','','o','','','','w']

output = [v for i, v in enumerate(lis) if v != '' or i == 0 or (v == '' and lis[i-1] != '')]
print(output)
```

This will print:

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '', 'o', '', 'w']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools`. The idea here is to group according whether strings are empty, noting `bool('') == False`.

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

L = (list(j) if i else [''] for i, j in groupby(lis, key=bool))

res = list(chain.from_iterable(L))

print(res)

['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '', 'o', '', 'w']
```

Comment: If possible, Can you tell me how to do without using inbuilt libraries?

Comment: @merkle Use the equivalent implementations from the `itertools` docs: [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `zip()` within a list comprehension as following:

```
In [21]: lis = ['', '', 'h','e','l','l','','','','','o','','','','w', '', '']

In [22]: lis[:1] + [j for i, j in zip(lis, lis[1:]) if i or j]
Out[22]: ['', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '', 'o', '', 'w', '']
```

In this case we're looping over each pair an keeping the second item if one of the items in our pair is valid (not empty). You just then need to add the first item to the result because it's omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just a for loop?

```
new_list = []
for char in lis:
    if char == '' and new_list[-1] == '': continue
    new_list.append(char)
```

Outputs

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '', 'o', '', 'w']
```